# SVG focusable attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I used focusable attribute to force SVG elements get focus in HTML document.

I need to navigate in SVG elements in SVG tag by TAB key. Like mentioned in the document (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/interact.html#focusable-attr)

But I cannot do it. I have set the `focusable` attribute to `true`, and `tabindex` of each element to `0`.

Here is my code:

```
<div style="border: solid yellow 2px;" tabindex="0">
<svg tabindex="0" width="900px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 95 50" style="border: solid red 1px;" focusable="true"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g data-Name="group" tabindex="0" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5" data-tabindex="0" style="border: solid green 1px;" focusable="true">
        <circle tabindex="0" cx="20" cy="25" r="5" focusable="true" data-Name="shape 1"  data-tabindex="0" />
        <circle tabindex="0" cx="40" cy="25" r="5" focusable="true" data-Name="shape 2"  data-tabindex="0" />
        <circle tabindex="0" cx="60" cy="25" r="5" focusable="true" data-Name="shape 3" data-tabindex="0" />
        <circle tabindex="0" cx="80" cy="25" r="5" focusable="true" data-Name="shape 4" data-tabindex="0" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I have tested the code in Google Chrome. Is there any way to reach purpose?

Comment: Most browsers (including Chrome) only implement SVG 1.1 in general. SVG 1.1 doesn't have focusable but SVG 2 is coming and browsers will target that and it will have focusable (or some equivalent alternative)

Answer (score 34):

As @Robert Longson mentioned in the comments, SVG 1.2 was never finalized and SVG 1.2 Tiny is not implemented by web browsers.  SVG 2 will have a `tabIndex` attribute, with the same purpose as in HTML, but there are still some details to work out and many browsers have not implemented it yet (Chrome, IE and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778654) do respect `tabIndex` on SVG elements in HTML pages).

In the meantime, however, most browsers will allow `<a>` link elements in SVG to get keyboard focus if they have an `xlink:href` attribute (even if it is a no-op link like `#`).  You cannot control the tab order, or control focus from scripts, but you can allow users to cycle through elements, and the link will receive user input events.

The following snippet changes the styling of your circles when the link that contains them gets the user focus.

```css
svg {
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  }

a:focus {
  fill: blue;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="900px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 95 50" style="border: solid red 1px;"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g data-Name="group" stroke="green" fill="white" stroke-width="5" data-tabindex="0" >
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <circle cx="20" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 1"  data-tabindex="0" />
      </a>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 2"  data-tabindex="0" />
      </a>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <circle cx="60" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 3" data-tabindex="0" />
      </a>
      <a xlink:href="#">
        <circle cx="80" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 4" data-tabindex="0" />
      </a>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How many visits this Q&A will get now that it was [featured on CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/click-svg-to-focus/)? Great answer, @AmeliaBR

Comment: `focusable` seems have an effect in IE and Edge according to https://allyjs.io/data-tables/focusable.html#svg-element-ident-142

Comment: tabindex is now supported on all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/tabindex

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for a solution to navigate inside SVG for a while now, my intention is to have some SVG elements and navigate from one to another.
A good solution is this library: https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/releases My code that navigates from a node to another node is(navigates from yellow circle to red one):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.localScroll.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function( $ ){
   /**
    * Most jQuery.localScroll's settings, actually belong to jQuery.ScrollTo, check it's demo for an example of each option.
    * @see http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
    * You can use EVERY single setting of jQuery.ScrollTo, in the settings hash you send to jQuery.localScroll.
    */
   
   // The default axis is 'y', but in this demo, I want to scroll both
   // You can modify any default like this
   $.localScroll.defaults.axis = 'xy';
   
   $.localScroll({
    //target: '#content', // could be a selector or a jQuery object too.
    queue:true,
    duration:1000,
    hash:true,
    lazy:true,
    onBefore:function( e, anchor, $target ){
     // The 'this' is the settings object, can be modified
    },
    onAfter:function( anchor, settings ){
     // The 'this' contains the scrolled element (#content)
    }
   });
   
   $('#nodeX').click(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTo(document.getElementById('node1'), 1000);
   });
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>

<svg id="panel" width="3249pt" height="2200pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 3249.00 2200.00" >

<g id="nodeX">
 <a xlink:href="#node1">
 <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
 </a>
 </g>

 <g id="node1">
 <circle cx="1880" cy="1580" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="red" />
 </g>
 
</svg>

</body>
```