# Cannot get keyboard focused for <a> link elements in SVG under Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, svg, focusable

I want to focus a object through keyboard's TAB key by adding `<a>` link surrounding some other tags like `<path>`, etc. Here is a reference link: [SVG focusable attribute is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671799/svg-focusable-attribute-is-not-working#new-answer)
Using the method in the link above, I can successfully focus the object I want under Chrome, but it won't work under Firefox, can anybody tell why Firefox does not support this? Thanks

Comment: I had this exactly same problem before: it works on Chrome but not on Firefox (this was 2 months ago, I don't have information regarding new versions of Firefox).

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, it seems not supported on Firefox :(

Comment: Let's wait for SVG 2...

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, it seems not supported on Firefox. BTW, did you implement a feature that we can focus a svg graphic object through keyboard's TAB key? Is there another way we can do this except by adding an <a> tag inside the svg element?

Comment: No, I didn't implement anything... Leave the question here, let's see if someone has any tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabindex and focus/blur support for SVG has just been implemented in Firefox and [will appear in version 51](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778654).

You can see it in a [Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) right now if you want.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I noticed your mention and saw the bug fix about it. I tried to use tabindex and set its value to 0 in my code, it works well under Chrome! But still not work under the Nightly Build of Firefox. I downloaded it for Mac. Is our fix still not merged in?

Comment: There are a couple of bugs raised already about the implementation: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1302340 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1302341 if you think you've found a different issue, raise it in bugzilla so it can be fixed before Firefox 51 appears.

Comment: Thank you Robert, I've confirmed the latest Nightly build can work on the "tabindex" attribute. One more question, can the latest Firefox focus on a "<a xlink:href="#">" element? Does the link https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1302341 you mentioned means that we are going to support this?

Comment: I've create a new bug on bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303681.