# Style a Div to a Complex Shape

Tags: css

How can I came a div that looks like this:
[Arabesque Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scn2p.png) using css? Would it be a mix of triangle and circles? I'm not really sure.

Comment: Mmm that would look cool! Maybe also use border radius?

Comment: yeah you can rotate one div and then make four ciricles using border radius but I'm assuming you are okay with a solid color without outlines right?

Comment: At one time I would say that people need to remember that CSS is not a drawing program. While there are a number of people who took effort to create great things using CSS alone, I still think people need to remember that CSS is not a drawing program but a document styler.

Comment: I know it's not for drawing. But, for what I am trying to do I need a bunch of that shape that can be any size based on the text inside of it. So making <div> in that shape makes it much easier.

Comment: Try this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way but I agree other ways to do without just using a bunch of divs.

Markup:

```
<div class="shape-wrapper">
  <div class="shape-square"></div>
  <div class="shape-circle circle-top-left"></div>
  <div class="shape-circle circle-top-right"></div>
  <div class="shape-circle circle-bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="shape-circle circle-bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.shape-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
.shape-wrapper div {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
.shape-square {
  top: 15%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.shape-circle {
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 60%;
  -moz-border-radius: 60%;
  border-radius: 60%;
}

.circle-top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.circle-top-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.circle-top-right {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.circle-bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.circle-bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to create clickable chapes is with **svg images**.

[Guide to change the style of an SVG when you click on it](https://css-tricks.com/click-svg-to-focus/)

```css
a:focus {
  fill: pink;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 95 50">
  <a xlink:href="#0">
    <circle cx="20" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 1" data-tabindex="0" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#0">
    <circle cx="40" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 2" data-tabindex="0" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#0">
    <circle cx="60" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 3" data-tabindex="0" />
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#0">
    <circle cx="80" cy="25" r="5" data-Name="shape 4" data-tabindex="0" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

The guide references an other ["similar" stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671799/svg-focusable-attribute-is-not-working)

Of course, this element is not a "div" but I would suppose that you want to click or colorise this shape which are doable with an SVG.

Comment: He wants to use a div so you aren't answering the question.

Comment: Yeah, that does not really help, but thanks. I want to use div, and my problem is with the creation of shape not the clicking.

Comment: @Rob You are right. This is still the most simple/logical way in my opinion (from what I know) to show/interact with "arabesque"/weird shaped DOM objects.

Comment: Like @Rob said in a comment on your question "CSS is not a drawing program". Rob also said "there are a number of people who took effort to create great things using CSS alone".

Here are good examples of efforst:
http://www.svennerberg.com/2008/09/imagemap-rollover/ (maybe you can ignore the javascript?) https://stackoverflow.com/a/12128398/6529948